# Ubuntu Linux installer does not detect installed Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I try to install Ubuntu Linux on my laptop alongside Windows 7 x64, that are already installed using a bootable USB flash drive.

When I am in the live USB in Linux I can see all my Windows files, but the installer says that there are no detected operating systems in my machine? I tried the same thing with Linux Mint installer and had the exact same results!

And when I click on “something else” option all I can see is my whole hard disk as free space even though I created a 50GB partition from Windows Disk Management. See screenshot below.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I don't want to create a new partition from linux because I am afraid that it will destroy windows as long as linux doesn't see other operating system. Do you think it's safe?

Answer (score 0):

First choose “Try Ubuntu", then open the Terminal.

Open a terminal window, e.g. by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Enter the command:

```
$ WINOSDATA=true ubiquity
```

For details: You can test this by running first:

```
$ sudo os-prober
```

And then:

```
$ sudo WINOSDATA=true os-prober
```

You may find that in the first case, no OS is detected, but in the second, Windows 8 is detected.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQT45W4uw00